# Can Laravel Dusk Assert a JavaScript Dynamic Element?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I have a form created by JavaScript and I can see it in the Chrome developer tool: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, but I can't see it in view-source: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

I want to test, but Laravel Dusk can't see it. Is it possible that Laravel Dusk asserts (see, press, click, input, etc.) JavaScript dynamic element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let dusk wait until your dynamic elements are available:

[Waiting For Elements:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk#waiting-for-elements)

> If you need to pause the test for a given number of milliseconds, use
>   the pause method:

```
$browser->pause(1000);
```

> The waitFor method may be used to pause the execution of the test
>   until the element matching the given CSS selector is displayed on the
>   page. By default, this will pause the test for a maximum of five
>   seconds before throwing an exception. If necessary, you may pass a
>   custom timeout threshold as the second argument to the method:

```
// Wait a maximum of five seconds for the selector...
$browser->waitFor('.selector');

// Wait a maximum of one second for the selector...
$browser->waitFor('.selector', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you! $browser->waitFor works for me! You save my day!